# Failure to detect "Keypress" on QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qtableview

I'm using `QTableView` to visualize some particular images. The user may click on the images of the TableView and that image will be magnified in another bigger window of `QLabel` type. I'm able to make this possible using the mouse clicks on the TableView, but I'd like to enable it for keyboard buttons **"up"** and **"down"**. What I mean is that, once the user click on one of the images listed on the TableView, if the user changes to other images using keyboard buttons **"up"** and **"down"**, I want to detect key press and connect it to the `QLabel` which magnifies that particular selected image.

So, what I mean is I actually want to detect `keypress` on the `QTableView`. Until now I haven't managed to do it. I'm installing an `eventfilter`on the `viewPort` of the `QTableView`, and in the `eventfilter` function I can detect the `mousebuttonpress`, but I cannot detect the `keypress`.

To show you how I'm approaching the implementation I have made simple program for testing with `QTableView` and`Keypress`. Below, I have given the code of the `mainWindow` implementation of that simple program.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->numberTable->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
    connect(ui->FillUp, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(fillUp()));
}

void MainWindow::fillUp()
{
    model = new QStandardItemModel(3, 3, this);
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            QStandardItem * itm = new QStandardItem;
            counter++;
            itm->setText(QString::number(counter));
            model->setItem(i, j, itm);
        }
    }
    ui->numberTable->setModel(model);
    ui->numberTable->show();
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev)
{
    if(obj == ui->numberTable->viewport())
    {
        if(ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Mouse button pressed!\n";
        }
        else if(ev->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Key button pressed\n";
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, ev);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The programs does output **"Mouse button pressed"**, but no output for keyboard pressing. Could you please let me know where I am doing the error?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try to install event filter on the table too: `ui->numberTable->installEventFilter(this);`? And removing `if(obj == ui->numberTable->viewport())` is worth to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same trouble. Using your idea, if print the type of event I get: "Paint widget" (12) instead "KeyPress" (6).

```
bool AR_Principal::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev){
    qDebug() << ev->type();
    if(obj == ui->tableView->viewport())
    {
        if(ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Mouse button pressed";
        }
        else if(ev->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Key button pressed";
        }
        else if(ev->type() == QEvent::Paint)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Paint widget" ;
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, ev);
}
```

If use QEvent::Paint event this works. Or like the other answer says add:

```
ui->tableView->installEventFilter(this);
```

And dont use the condition:

```
if(obj == ui->tableView->viewport())
```

But a more efficient solution its:

```
connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged (const QModelIndex & , const QModelIndex & )), SLOT(selectedItem(const QModelIndex &)));
```

Where selectedItem(const QModelIndex &) its a private slot function where you can do anything with selected data (using their index)